# OpenCV3.0 gold imread function doesn't work with absolute path on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0

I use imread function by OpenCV3.0 gold on Ubuntu 14.04, and followed the [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726768/opencv-3-0-trouble-with-installation) to installed OpenCV3.0  But the imread function dosen't work with absolute path.It can work like imread("a.jpg"),but not imread("\home\a\a.jpg") .I want to use the function to read image sequence.Here is my code:

```
  char filename1[200];
  char filename2[200];
  sprintf(filename1, "/home/image_2/%06d.png", 0);
  sprintf(filename2, "/home/image_2/%06d.png", 1);


  //read the first two frames from the dataset
  Mat img_1_c = imread(filename1);
  Mat img_2_c = imread(filename2);

  if ( !img_1_c.data || !img_2_c.data ) { 
   std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
   }
```

There are images in folder a,like 000000.png .When I run it ,it says"--(!) Error reading images".Can someone help me ?Thank you.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31342428/5008845) in case it's something trivial.

Comment: @Miki    Thank you all the same.