# compiling code with opencv - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lippicv

Tags: c++, opencv

When compiling some code with `opencv` I get this error

```
# g++ txtbin-03.1.cpp -o txtbin `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lippicv
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

## installing opencv

```
# apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
# apt-get install libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
# cd /var/bin && git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git && cd opencv
# cmake . && make -j2 && make install
```

Comment: Did you check this question and answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726768/opencv-3-0-trouble-with-installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recompile OpenCv using following option:

```
cmake -DWITH_IPP=ON . && make -j $(nproc) && make install
```

Comment: Where to add the line? Cant find `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(` or any of the other lines arround

Comment: Are you compiling openCV  ?

Comment: Yup, so during compilation have you on lippicv  library

Comment: Compile OpenCv with option : WITH_IPP=ON

Comment: but I cant find where to add the line to `CMakeLists.txt:`.... When I search the text file I cant find `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`

Comment: First tried to compile OpvenCv with option "WITH_IPP=ON" and check if you got error or Not ?

Comment: If you successfully done, than did not edit CMakeLists.txt. Which version of OpenCv you used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98675/discussion-between-dipak-d-desai-and-clarkk).

Answer (score 15):

In my case, all it took was to copy libippicv.a from the OpenCV SDK to /usr/local/lib:

```
sudo cp 3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/lib/intel64/libippicv.a /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: this should be the best fix.

Answer (score 5):

Recompiling whole library isn't necessary, especially if you don't need this library. I found great and instantly working solution [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/85635/error-cannot-find-lippicv/?answer=85676#post-id-85676%22here%22). In case link expired or broke:

The solution is simply to remove `-lippicv` from opencv pkg-config configuration file. So you have to locate `opencv.pc` file, which default is in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/` directory. Then from section `Libs:` just remove aforementioned library.

Answer (score 0):

**libippicv.a** is a third party library, so you need to explicitly provide it during compilation or make it part of your execution environment.

It is located in ~/OpenCV/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/lib/intel64/

Also, provide cmake **-DWITH_IPP=ON** at the time of Makefile generation.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem while trying to install the opencv_contrib repository (opencv-3.1.0/Ubuntu 16.04), and none of the solutions worked (I tried to make OpenCV with flag `WITH_IPP=ON`, but somehow OpenCV 3.1.0 failed to download the `ippicv` library(?) and there was no error prompt so I only figured this out when I tried to `locate ippicv` in terminal).

My solution was to download another OpenCV build (3.0.0 worked for me), make + make install with flag `WITH_IPP=ON`, and then copy the downloaded ippicv library (which should be located in `/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a` by now) to `/usr/local/lib/`.

I don't know if this is a known bug in OpenCV 3.1.0, but this one is definitely worth keeping an eye out for.