# Impossible to install OpenCV Ubuntu (libopencv_core error)

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.0 for Python on Ubuntu 14.04 but after many installations (and StackOverflow pages read) it still does not work.

In Python (Python 2.7) when importing typing `import cv2` I obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have seen that this error may be due to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf` and therefore I wrote inside it the line `/usr/local/opencv/` but it did not help (actually there is no folder `opencv`in `/usr/local/` on my computer...

For the installation I followed the instructions on this website: http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/

I suspect errors occurred during the `cmake` phase because I got failures like `-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed`. I don't know what that means and if it is important for the installation...

I have other errors like

`-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'`

`--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found`

During the `make` phase I obtained this error

```
[ 31%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/qrc_window_QT.cpp.o
In file included from /home/xavier/OpenCV/build/modules/highgui/qrc_window_QT.cpp:9:0:
/home/xavier/OpenCV/build/modules/highgui/qrc_window_QT.cpp: In function ‘int qInitResources_window_QT()’:
/home/xavier/OpenCV/build/modules/highgui/qrc_window_QT.cpp:1749:25: warning: no previous declaration for ‘int qInitResources_window_QT()’ [-Wmissing-declarations]
int QT_MANGLE_NAMESPACE(qInitResources_window_QT)()
^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:100:36: note: in definition of macro ‘QT_MANGLE_NAMESPACE’
# define QT_MANGLE_NAMESPACE(name) name
^
/home/xavier/OpenCV/build/modules/highgui/qrc_window_QT.cpp: In function ‘int qCleanupResources_window_QT()’:
/home/xavier/OpenCV/build/modules/highgui/qrc_window_QT.cpp:1758:25: warning: no previous declaration for ‘int qCleanupResources_window_QT()’ [-Wmissing-declarations]
int QT_MANGLE_NAMESPACE(qCleanupResources_window_QT)()
^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:100:36: note: in definition of macro ‘QT_MANGLE_NAMESPACE’
# define QT_MANGLE_NAMESPACE(name) name
^
[ 31%] Generating opencl_kernels_superres.cpp, opencl_kernels_superres.hpp
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: it seems you have an old OpenCV version (2.4.something) already installed that conflicts with 3.0

Comment: yes it may be the case but I tried to remove opencv before installing the 3.0 version (with `sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;` and `sudo make unistall`). But maybe it did not work. What do I have to do?

Comment: No idea on linux ;D. I was just giving you some pointers of the possible problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problems. Since this may interested other people, here how I proceed.

1. I removed entirely opencv from my computer:

   - `sudo make unistall` in the repository where I wrote `sudo make install`
   - `sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;` to remove all files containing "opencv"
   - `sudo find / -name "*cv2.so*" -exec rm -i {} \;` to remove all files containing "cv2.so"
   - `conda uninstall opencv` (if needed)
2. I followed [this link](https://junise.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/how-to-install-opencv-2-4-10-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) to install OpenCV2.4.10 for Python2.7: I did **only** the points 5,6,7 and 12 (the remaining ones are useless for what I wanted). I changed a bit the `cmake` command and I typed

   ```
   cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON  -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_VTK=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON ..
   ```
3. Now if when typing `import cv2` in Python you get an error like "No module named cv2", edit your `.bashrc` file with the following command

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
   ```

You will have to reload the .bashrc file (`source .bahsrc`) to apply the change.

4. Finally I rebooted my computer. And it worked!

To conclude, I don't know why it did not work previously but it appears that with this version of OpenCV I did not encounter any problem!

Good luck!

Comment: I find ``sudo find / -name "$ANYTHING_WITH_WILDCARDS" -exec rm -i {} \;`` a little bit unsettling.

Comment: I found that on http://askubuntu.com/questions/564290/how-to-uninstall-opencv-2-4-9-completely-from-ubuntu. It works quite well and helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You didn't install it correctly that's why you can't import it. Here is a guide on how to install it, (it is for an .older version but the commands are the same). [OpenCV 3.0 Trouble with Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726768/opencv-3-0-trouble-with-installation)

Comment: I get the error `ImportError: libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` on Python 2 and `ImportError: libopencv_core.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` on Python3...

Comment: Are you getting any errors when executing the first command of the installation guide?

Comment: the `cmake` one? yes I get some errors like the ones I described in my initial post